# Enforce unique constraint only on some queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I've got an accounts table, and in that table I've got a `profile_id` column. I'd like to be able to have multiple rows in the column with the same `profile_id`, but I'd also like to be able to say "insert iff no other row has this `profile_id` value." Normally, I'd use a unique constraint for this, but that offers me no way to override it when I expect the `profile_id` to exist.

Is there a way to (without race conditions) have an insert error or fail if a value already exists, or alternatively, have an insert ignore a constraint and enter values that don't match the constraint?

Comment: Please provide sample data to clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Assume schema has a `num` column.

I want to be able to insert 1 to that num column, then try to insert 1 again, and it fails. Like a unique constraint.

But then I _also_, at the query level, want to be able to say "I expect 1 to already exist, and want to insert another 1 anyways", essentially overriding the unique constraint.

I don't know what sample data would illustrate this.

Comment: You can't insert into a column. You can insert a *row* into a *table*. Sounds like you have two data use cases: (1) Inserting a new row with a duplicated value should fail, and (2) Inserting a new row with a duplicated value should succeed. Do I have it right? How do you expect the system to distinguish between the two cases? Will you be passing a flag or something?

Comment: That is correct, sometimes I want the inserted row to succeed, sometimes I want it to fail, depending on which query I'm running. I was hoping there was a way to modify the insert statement to make it either succeed or fail when otherwise it wouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could build a partial index; it is at least a partial solution to your problem.  That is, define a column that says something like:

```
only_uniques_allowed
```

And then build the index:

```
create unique index unq_t_profile_id_uniques on (profile_id) where only_uniques_allowed;
```

Then, any row that has `only_uniques_allowed` set to true would have a unique `profile_id` *among the rows with this setting*.

However, you don't really want to enforce a constraint, so perhaps what you want to do is better done at the application level.  Or perhaps it suggests that you need a different data model.

Comment: I had thought of the `only_uniques_allowed` solution, but wouldn't that limit me to two rows with the same value? One with `only_uniques_allowed = True` and the other with `only_uniques_allowed = False`? And sorry for the silly question, but what makes that index a partial index? It seems like a regular [multi-column index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/indexes-multicolumn.html) to me?

Comment: @Paddy . . . The `where` clause makes it a partial index ;)  Now that I've edited the answer to express what I intend.

Comment: Ah, so similar to [this method](https://medium.com/little-programming-joys/unique-partial-indexes-with-postgresql-86e137905c12), then? (Which I found once you told me the phrase I was looking for was "partial index".) That sounds like a plausible answer, I'll give it a shot and come back and accept this answer if it turns out to work as I hoped. Out of curiosity, what made it only a "partial solution"?

Comment: @Paddy . . . Because you can still have duplicates, as you mentioned, one on a row with a "true" flag and one on a row with a "false" flag.

Comment: Are you saying I can only have, max, two with the same profile_id in the table? Sorry, I'm unclear on that point.

Comment: @Paddy . . . No, you can have any number on rows where the flag is false.  You can have only one where the flag is true.

Comment: That sounds like what I want. Also, according to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9759/postgresql-multi-column-unique-constraint-and-null-values), I can have as many `NULL` rows as I want just using a multicolumn unique constraint, as NULLs aren't compared as "equal". So I think I can do it even without the partial index, just using `True` for the ones where I want the unique check, and `NULL` for the ones where I don't.